# Automatic Template Specialization in Template Function Argument

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I came up with the following problem (code below):

```
template<class T>
void printname(const T& t){std::cout<<t<<std::endl;}

template<class T>
void applyfunc(const T& t, void (*f)(const T& )){(*f)(t);}
int main(){
    const int a=1;
    applyfunc(a,printname);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that it compiles with vc++8(VS2005), and GCC, CLang (on Ubuntu 12.04)
but fails to compile with vc++ 2008 express.

It seems to be legal code but I don't really get why.

If anyone could explain it I'd appreciate it.

Supposing it is legal, is there any way that something similar could be done with functors?

Comment: What error do you get with VS2008 Express?

Comment: Are you asking why VS2008 rejects the code, or why the others accept it? *It seems to be legal code but I don't really get why* Also, I am not sure what *is there any way that something similar could be done with functors?* really means. What is the something similar that you'd like done?

Comment: @Praetorian: C2896,C2784 cannot use function template void (*)(const T& ) as function argument

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: First question: yes, second question was answered by Igor Tandetnik below.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you meant to use `func` for `printname` (or vice versa).

For what it's worth, I believe this code to be legal, and the fact that VS2008 (and also VS2010; I don't have VS2012 handy at the moment) rejects it looks like a compiler bug.

Re: something similar with functors - see if this does it for you:

```
#include <iostream>

struct printname {
  template<class T>
  void operator()(const T& t) { std::cout<<t<<std::endl; }
};

template<class T, class F>
void applyfunc(const T& t, F f) { f(t); }

int main(){
  const int a=1;
  applyfunc(a, printname());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've only tried the case when the functor itself was templated, and not its member function. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as of whether the question is why it works in most compilers or why it fails in VS2008. If the question is the former, we can discuss a simplified version of this:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T const &) {}

void g(void (*fn)(std::string const&) {}

g(f); // compiles
void (*fn)(double const &) = f;
```

Pointers to functions are a bit special in the language, since the same name can refer to different overloads. When the name of a function is used in code, the compiler cannot determine which of the overloads is determined by itself, so it will use the *target* of the expression to determine this. In the case of `g(f)`, since the `g` function takes a function of type `void (std::string const&)`, it will resolve `f` to mean `f<std::string>`, while in the case of the initialization of `fn` the compiler will resolve to the specialization `f<double>`.

Note that this is a **very commonly used** feature of the language:

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The name `std::endl` refers to a template:

```
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
```

The compiler sees that this is being called on the object `std::cout`, of type `basic_ostream<char,char_traits<char>>`, and that the only specialization that matches the call to `operator<<` is that where `charT == char` and `traits == char_traits<char>` and picks the correct specialization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I'd posted my question I've checked the standard, and my code in the post is correct as you've explained.

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio 2010, the solution is easy yet subtle.  You simply need to add `<int>` after printname in the line `applyfunc(a,printname<int>);`.  The compiler needs help figuring out the template type to use.

```
#include <iostream>

struct printname
{
   template<class T>
   void operator()(const T& t)
   {
      std::cout << t << std::endl;
   }
};

template<class T, class F>
void applyfunc(const T& t, F f)
{
   f(t);
}

int main()
{
  const int a=1;
  applyfunc(a, printname<int>);      // Add <int> here
  return 0;
}
```